# Block Specific settings in Android for self control

Tags: google-play-store, settings, browser, accessibility, private-dns

Is there any way to block changing of specific settings in Android. Like I am using Familysafe dns to avoid pornography on my device. Is there any way I can lock that specific setting on my device. There is a app named BlockerHero which used to block the changing of this setting until the accountability partner approves. But this feature does not seem to work now and only uninstall works. There is one more app by Cleanbrowsing which blocks this page. But it does not work sometimes. I don't have a rooted device.

If you know any such app or workaround please include it in the answer.

Comment: Whatever you can do you can later undo. The help you need - or actually don't because there's nothing wrong with some sassy pics or vids - isn't technical. And your question is off-topic anyway.